# logging all the information's of ADF pipelines on every run into a table

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have created a ADF pipeline which picks up the files does processing of the files and project it to Power BI, want to log all the information to a table as part of logging.
what all information should I log into the table? and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

> want to log all the information to a table as part of logging

Use Copy Activity and add source as input from other activities also use sink as SQL Server.

You can use below query and add it to Add dynamic content:

```
SELECT ‘@{pipeline().DataFactory}’ as DataFactory_Name,
‘@{pipeline().Pipeline}’ as Pipeline_Name,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.executionDetails[0].source.type}’ as Source_Type,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.executionDetails[0].sink.type}’ as Sink_Type,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.executionDetails[0].status}’ as Execution_Status,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.rowsRead}’ as RowsRead,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.rowsCopied}’ as RowsWritten
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.copyDuration}’ as CopyDurationInSecs,
‘@{activity(‘copytables’).output.executionDetails[0].start}’ as CopyActivity_Start_Time,
‘@{utcnow()}’ as CopyActivity_End_Time,
‘@{pipeline().RunId}’ as RunId,
‘@{pipeline().TriggerType}’ as TriggerType,
‘@{pipeline().TriggerName}’ as TriggerName,
‘@{pipeline().TriggerTime}’ as TriggerTime
```

Refer this [article](https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/01/10/log-pipeline-executions-to-file-in-azure-data-factory/) by Rohit Dhande for more information